# javascript, php loop on dynamic filename audio, audio file is not opening

Tags: php, loops, audio

on loop the image file name is changing but audio file name is not changing so each time button play same audio while image is diffrent

```
<?php
$pth1="voice/alifbepati/";
    $pth="images/ipapati/";
for ($x = 1; $x <= 52; $x++) {

echo $pth1.$x.".mp3";
global $filenm;
$filenm= $pth1.$x.".mp3";
echo "<img src=\"$pth".$x.".jpg\" width=75 height=75><BR>
<audio id=\"player\" src='$filenm'></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick=\"document.getElementById('player').play()\" title='$filenm'>Play</button>

</div>
   The number is: $x <br>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: its due to same id for all elements .you want to use dynamic ids

Comment: thank you i got it..... this is working fine    <audio id=\"player$x\" src='$filenm'></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick=\"document.getElementById('player$x').play()\" title='$filenm'>Play</button>
    
</div>